# How to store/deal with django exception webpages in acceptance testing

Tags: python, django, selenium

I am running a series of selenium functional tests of a django site for acceptance testing purposes. I notice that when I run these and exceptions occur, I get back an entire page ( eg a HTTP status 500 ).

I am running acceptance testing using a simple loop and storing the outputted html to a db using the django orm:

```
def my_functional_tests(request):

    import requests
    from mytests.models import Entry    


    for i in range(3):    


        p1 = { ....... }
        r1 = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/testfunction1/',data=p1)    

        ..............    

        entry = Entry(output1 = r1.text, output2 = r2.text, output3 = r3.text)
        entry.save()    

    return HttpResponse("completed")
```

My Model is defined as (where the outputs are the HTML results of 3 functional tests ):

```
class Entry(models.Model):    

    output1 = models.CharField(max_length=240)
    output2 = models.CharField(max_length=240)
    output3 = models.CharField(max_length=240)
```

When I get an error, the resulting approximately 65K webpage causes an exception on saving, and breaks the testing.  I want to get as much info as possible, so I could increase  the max_length to lets say 70,000 to store the entire page, but is there a more concise way to capture and store relevant data including the specific errors to the db ?

Answer (score 1):

If you did this with Django's testing client, you could get more concise information--but by using requests, you're really hitting your page as a web browser would, so the full page is what you get (but 65K for a 500 Error page? Wow).

Could you embed in the error page an HTML comment with a marker and concise explanation?

```
<html>
  <h1>Error</h1>
  ... 64k of stuff follows ...
  <!-- ERR:"info about error" -->    
  </html>
```

That way, you could parse the results for that error code and store just that.

Of course, you'll want to make sure you don't put anything confidential in that error message or, if you do, that you emit it only when in DEBUG mode or when the request comes from localhost, or logged  in as staff, or whatever other security constraint would work.

Slightly prettier would be to write a piece of middleware that emits the error-info as an HTTP Header; then your page could stay the same and you could look at the response headers for your error info.